# Mi mensaje Toast de Contraseña incorrecta no aparece en mi app android

Tags: java, android-studio, contraseña, registro, android-toast

Al momento de registrar los datos de mi app funciona correctamente, excepto cuando pongo mal el usuario o contraseña, no me aparece el Toast **"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos"**
la app simplemente no hace nada

¿En qué parte debo poner el toast?

```
public void Ingresar(View view) {
        BaseDeDatosApp admin = new BaseDeDatosApp(this, "usuarios", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatosApp = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String usuario = et_usuario.getText().toString();
        String password = et_password.getText().toString();


        if (!usuario.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor Validar = BaseDeDatosApp.rawQuery("select * from usuarios where idsenati='" +
                    usuario + "' and contraseña='" + password + "'", null);
            try {
                if (Validar.moveToFirst()) {
                    String user = Validar.getString(0);
                    String pass = Validar.getString(3);
                    //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
                    if (usuario.equals(user) && password.equals(pass)) {
                        //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
                        //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
                        Intent ven = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
                        //lanzamos la actividad
                        startActivity(ven);
                        //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                        et_usuario.setText("");
                        et_password.setText("");
                    } else{//ESTE MENSAJE NO ME APARECE
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrio un Error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

        //////ds
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Completar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            BaseDeDatosApp.close();
        }
    }
```

He puesto el public void entero, y he puesto el MainActivity.this pero aun no me aparece el mensaje

Como puse, el registro me funciona bien, solo me aparece la siguiente activity cuando el usuario y contraseña son correctos

Comment: Y si desactivaste las notificaciones por accidente?

Comment: No entiendo, que notificaciones?

Comment: Las de la aplicación. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23710017/13419694

Comment: No, todas estan activadas

Comment: No se me ocurre que más podría ser. Pon un log justo antes de cada `Toast` que aparentemente no se muestra y mira el [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat). Sino aparece el log ahí, es porque simplemente esa parte del código no se está ejecutando.

Comment: Te sobra absolutamente por completo el siguiente código: `if (usuario.equals(user) && password.equals(pass))` puesto que tu query ya busca un usuario con ese nombre y contraseña... si lo encuentra, es que van a ser iguales. Nunca va a no entrar a ese if, por eso nunca se va a mostrar el toast. Es un error de la lógica de tu código.

Comment: Ya esta bien, ya lo arregle de otra forma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien lo que hice fue mover el else a el primer if

```
if (Validar.moveToFirst()) {
                String user = Validar.getString(0);
                String pass = Validar.getString(3);
                //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
                if (usuario.equals(user) && password.equals(pass)) {
                    //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
                    //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
                    Intent ven = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
                    //lanzamos la actividad
                    startActivity(ven);
                    //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                    et_usuario.setText("");
                    et_password.setText("");
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                BaseDeDatosApp.close();
            }
```

Comment: ¿Entonces qué era? ¿Simplemente no se llegaba a ejecutar el código?

Comment: SI, no se ejecutava en el if de equals

Answer (score 2):

Si ejecutas el `Toast` normalmente en un `Activity`, `this` alude a él. Pero viendo que usas `MainActivity.this` al crear un `Intent`, supongo que en este contexto `this` referencia a otro objeto.

Por lo tanto, es probable que también tengas que pasar el `Activity` de la misma manera.

Así:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Mensaje", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

---

En esta respuesta se hacen suposiciones ya que la pregunta enseña un fragmento limitado del código.

Sería necesario ver la clase completa para tener la certeza de que este es el motivo por el que el `Toast` no sé muestra.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya he cambiado lo que dijiste pero aun no aparece, tambien agrege el codigo entero

Comment: @JoseGodoyCebreros entonces por qué estabas usando `MainActivity.this` en un primer momento? ¿Había alguna necesidad de hacerlo?

Comment: Segun lo que veo es igual si pongo MainActivity.this o solo this, lo ponia para ahorrar código, igual sigue sin aparecerme el toast, disculpa las molestias